# Git Bash - Find commits merged from a deleted branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-bash

git acrobats here we go!

We have a branch X which was **merged** and **deleted**. Now we need to find all commits in master that were added as a part of the pull request merge of that branch X.

Physically, we are looking for all commits in master with source being that already deleted branch X

I don't see anything spefic in the git documentation, and have been searching for a while already on stack with no success. The best would be to have a --diff for the changes

How can we do it?

Comment: `git diff <commit before branch creation>..<last commit of that branch before merge>`?

Comment: You say "pull request" : are you using the pull requests of a known service ? github ? gitlab ? azure devops ?

Comment: We don't know what was the best and last commitID @dan1st - its an old branch where we didn't have conventional commits or tickets in the commit message.

Comment: @LeGEC tfs but 2013 sadly so its good only for viewing minor things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the id of the merge commit (let's call it `<merge>`), you can let git compute the merge base for you :

```
git log <merge>^..<merge>^2
```

If you want to view the global diff of what changes were brought to master :

```
git diff <merge>^...<merge>^2  # three dots
```

---

The merge commit has 2 parents, its first parent should be the previous state of your `master` branch, and its second parent the state of the feature branch when it was merged.

If `name` points to a commit (anything works : a commit id, a branch name, a tag name, `HEAD~10` ...), then :

- `name^` points to its first parent
- `name^2` points to its second parent (if it has one : it will error if `name` isn't a merge commit)